# How to update a JSON data that came from a mysql database using laravel or just a native php?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I have a database table with a type of longtext since I changed the structure to JSON because I will put a JSON data there and inserting there is is just fine. My problem is I want to update a part of that JSON data after retrieving it using laravel/php.

I tried it by using the code below but I have a hard time accomplishing it.

```
$qtyy = $orderDetail->quantity;  
$product = Product::findOrFail($prod_id);  
$json = json_decode($product->variations, true);  
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {  
if($key == $orderDetail->variation){  
    $total = (int)$value->qty + (int)$qtyy;  
    DB::table('products')  
        ->where('id', $prod_id)  
        ->update([$value->qty => $total]);  
    }  
}
```

I want to change the "qty" in my database

```
{ 
   "AliceBlue-Cream":{ 
      "price":"500",
      "sku":"V-AliceBlue-Cream",
      "qty":"1000"
   },
   "Amethyst-Cream":{ 
      "price":"500",
      "sku":"V-Amethyst-Cream",
      "qty":"2998"             <- I want to update that
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the attribute casting, from laravel docs:

> if your database has a JSON or TEXT field type that contains
>   serialized JSON, adding the array cast to that attribute will
>   automatically deserialize

simply add casts array to your model with your column name:

```
protected $casts = [
        'myColumn' => 'array',
    ];
```

Later when you're ready to update its value:

```
$product = Product::find(1);
$myUpdatedColumn = $product->myColumn;
$myUpdatedColumn['qty'] = 2998;
$product->myColumn = $myUpdatedColumn;
$product->save();
```

Comment: I didn't use my model to query. I use the DB class to query in the database. Is it okay?

Comment: That will work on eloquent model only, just switch your query builder with model, I can see you've already got the Product model

Comment: Okay, ill try thanks. I'll comment here later if I will able to make it run.

Answer (score 2):

try this one, that's work for me!

```
DB::table('products')  
    ->where('id', $prod_id)
    ->update([
         "Amethyst-Cream->qty" => "2998"
      ]);
```

Comment: I need to udpate it dynamically. I dont know why I cant do it. Is there any problem with my code?

Comment: May I know whats the difference of your answer to mine?